# Relational database design - I want an extra field for some row types but not all

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization, database-schema

This a very basic database design/normalisation question.

Suppose I have a `Books` table with the following columns:

```
isbn|title|author|status
```

and `status` can be one of `checked out`, `available`, `overdue`, `lost` (stored as integers).

When adding rows I decide "actually, when the status is `checked out`, I want to store another field `due_date`". *I only want to store this field for books with status checked out*, as it has no meaning otherwise.

**What is the standard, correct, canonical way to do this?**

One approach is to add the column and set it to `NULL` if the status is not `checked out`, but this sounds like a bad idea to me (for integrity among other things, e.g. what if the status is `available` and we also have a `due_date`?)

The other obvious answer is to create a `DueDates` table and store `isbn|due_date` pairs in it. This is the approach I normally take but it's easy to end up with tables and `JOIN`s all over the place.

I am not looking for how to store books specifically, that's just an example of the problem and I want to know the standard solution.

**Edit**: Does the answer change if I decide that I want to add *lots* of fields for `checked out` status only (`due_date`, `borrowed_by`, `checked_out_from`, ...) - and have all these as `NULL` if the status is not `checked out`?

Comment: From a *practical* standpoint, in e.g. SQL, we can implement a `CHECK` constraint, such that `status = checked out` and `due_date is not null`, or `status != checked out` and `due_date is null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem as you have stated it is fundamentally one of typing and subtyping.  a "checked out book" is a type of book.  an "available book" is a different type of book.  A book can progress from state to state over time, and can thus belong in one subtype or another over time.

In Object modeling, this kind of issue is handled through classes, subclasses, and inheritance.

In ER modeling, this kind of issue is called "specialization".  You can find articles on the web dealing with ER specialization.  I have not seen examples that deal with time varying specialization.  More of the examples are time invarying, like the Pets case.

In relational modeling and relational database design, there are several standard ways of building tables to implement specialization.

The first standard way is called "Single Table Inheritance".  This is basically what you've designed.  You end up with a lot of NULLs for data that does not pertain to the subtype of a given row.  But you don't have to do any joins.

A second standard way is called "Class Table Inheritance".  In this way, there is a separate table for each class and subclass, and they have a shared primary key. You can look up both "Class Table Inheritance" and "Shared Primary Key" in SO and on the web.  You do more joining, but you have fewer NULLS.

There are other ways.

Which way is best depends on the case at hand.

Answer (score 3):

The approach I use for these cases is to add a column which is optional and a check constraint to make sure that the column is filled (ie is not null) when another column has a certain value and empty (ie is null) when the other column has other values.

In your case, the constraint could be written as

```
CHECK ((due_date IS NOT NULL) = (status = 'CHECKED OUT'))
```

If multiple columns need to be checked, either add several constraints, one for each column, or combine them into one check constraint by listing all the valid combinations:

```
CHECK (status = 'A' AND due_date IS NULL OR status = 'B' AND due_date is NULL
OR status = 'C' AND due_date IS NOT NULL OR status = 'D' AND due_date IS NOT NULL)
```

**NB** AND has higher precedence than OR so brackets aren't necessary in this case but you may wish to add them for clarity.

Adding a separate table makes this more difficult, if not impossible in most DBMS products as a check constraint may not query another table.

Comment: Thanks, and what if I want to add many fields for that one status only (see edit)? Would you still use check constraints and add to the main table?

Comment: Note that that solution doesn't work for the example, because due_date is also non-null for 'OVERDUE'.

Comment: Also, why does "Adding a separate table makes this more difficult, if not impossible in most DBMS products"? Surely you could just do the check against the foreign key rather than the due date column?

Comment: It's not possible to query another table in a check constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a strict normalised data structure, then using the duedates table is more normalised.

Having a due date that depends on the status is a multivalued dependency, and hence breach of 4th normal form.

This doesn't avoid your problem of having a status of "checked_out" and a due_date - it is equally possible to have an entry in the duedates table when the status is available as it is to have an entry in the duedate field.

(As an aside, in this library example, I would separate the loans from the "lost" status of the books)

Comment: I see what you mean.. does this mean that strictly normalising can actually make it _harder_ to enforce data integrity?

Comment: I would say it is more symptomatic ( a data smell, if you like) of an underlying flaw in the design - ie: because "Available" means not on loan, then "available/on loan" is superfluous - see the "loans" table note

Comment: Ok, but then a simple query based on `status` like 'select all books that are available' becomes 'select all books not in loans table' which is more complex (I guess).

Comment: That's a fairly simple (left) join

Comment: You are right. I just feel like there must be cases where reorganising the schema isn't possible. See the 'Pets' example comment on @deworde's answer. Or does the need for these 'extra columns' always indicate a design flaw?

Comment: Of course, there are exceptions, but in general, yes - columns that depend on the values in other columns are a breach of 4NF and as such a design flaw. Regarding pets, this is a fairly good document on inheritance (as that is effectively what we're talking about ) http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-mapping-to-rdb/ - what if you want to store different additional information about cats, or birds. Then you'd have a bunch of random columns.

Comment: @Andrew You're experiencing the true tragedy of software development and architecture: The Universe is very poorly designed...

Comment: @podiluska thanks, this is exactly what I'm talking about. Interestingly that paper gives 'Using one data entity for an entire class hierarchy' (with blank columns) as one valid option. I'd be interested to know how much space all the NULLs would waste.

Answer (score 1):

I would still add the column to the base table and define a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to make sure the `DueDate` is NULL when the value in status is not equal to `CHECKED OUT`.

Normalizing and storing the ISBN -> Due date mapping in a different table requires application layer code to ensure that ISBN's whose STATUS is not CHECKED OUT doesn't end up in that table.

Answer (score 1):

**REMOVING REDUNDANT DATA IS BETTER THAN ATTEMPTING TO ENFORCE CHECKS TO KEEP IT IN SYNC**

Your real issue in the first example is that your status column is duplicating information held elsewhere and in more detail by the due_date.

Specifically, the statuses "On Loan", "Available" and "Overdue" are all based on the due_date, and therefore you're attempting to enforce that the data be kept in sync. It would be better to simplify the system to no longer store duplicate data that needs to be synced.

For the second example given in the comments, I think Colin's answer is the correct way to go, but it would always be my second choice over designing the database to reduce examples of these constraints.

Comment: Thanks. My issue isn't actually with books though. I want to know in the general case, how to add columns for some row 'types' and not others.

Comment: @Andrew: Understood, but it still brings us back to *why* you're doing that. It generally suggests the same issue: You've got redundant data that needs to be kept in sync (e.g. the "type" column and the foreign key)

Comment: What about another example - I have a 'Pets' table with an 'Animal type' column (cat dog bird etc). If it's a dog I want to store the breed, otherwise I don't care. What would you do here? (I'm just trying to work out if generally, having a type column with additional data for some types indicates bad design.)

Comment: That's a better example, in which case I think Colin's answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your initial model (definition). There is a difference between physical book (book on the media) and a generic book `{ISBN, Title, Author}`. When you look at the table in your example, there is a dependency `FD{ISBN} --> {Title, Author}`, but `{Status}` is not dependent on {ISBN} -- so the status does not belong in this table.

[image]

Essentially, status is a derived attribute

```
select
      c.ISBN
    , b.BookTitle
    , c.BookCopyNo
    , case
      when  ReturnDate is not null                              then 'available'
      when (ReturnDate is null) and (current_date < DueDate)    then 'checked out'
      when (ReturnDate is null) and ((current_date - DueDate) >= 100 ) then 'lost'
      when (ReturnDate is null) and (current_date > DueDate)    then 'overdue'   
      end as BookStatus

from CheckOut as c
join Book     as b on b.ISBN = c.ISBN
where c.CheckOutDate = (select max(xx.CheckOutDate)
                          from CheckOut as xx
                         where xx.ISBN       = c.ISBN
                           and xx.BookCopyNo = c.BookCopyNo)
;
```

Comment: I think this is a similar explanation to mine. I'd be more interested to see your answer to his Pets example he gave in my comments, which I think has less data duplication issues.

Comment: @deworde; that is not the same, BookStatus changes frequently over time, while the pets example is plain super-type/subtype.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. How would you solve the plain super-type/sub-type problem, or is there an answer to this already on the site?